# syntax error verilog code

Tags: verilog, ise

this  sub-code  that read the selection line s4-s1 and take the summation of a,b in the selection line =0000,  When running this code in ISE project negotiator  it gives syntax error tell " Syntax error near "=" " in the line z=0 in the if statement

can you tell me why ?

```
module one1(a,b,s1,s2,s3,s4,f );
  input s1,s2,s3,s4;
  input [3:0] a,b;
  output reg [3:0] f;

  reg  z,n,c;

  //0000

  if ({s4,s3,s2,s1} == 4'b0000)
  begin
    assign {c,f}= a+b; 
    if (f==0) 
      z=1;         //here is the error 
    else z=0;
    n=f[3];
  end

endmodule
```

Answer (score 4):

Two problems:

1. You need to wrap an always block around your combinational logic.  Something like always @* begin

then put your if statement in there.

2. You can't assign a wire inside an always block.  you need a reg.

Comment: "you need a reg."... or move the assign statement outside the if block.